# How to find sum of multiple columns each seperately which have on column with same value?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have a table with `invoice_id` `quantity` `rate`, now i need to find the sum of `quantity` and `rate` seperately with same `invoice_id`.

```
$invoices_quantity = Sale::selectRaw('sum(quantity) as quantity,invoice_id')->groupBy('invoice_id')->pluck('quantity','invoice_id');
```

this only shows result of one field,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find sum of multiple columns like this:

```
 $invoices_quantity = Sale::select(
                           DB::raw('sum(quantity) as quantity_count'),
                           DB::raw('sum('rate') as rate_count')
                       ->groupBy('invoice_id')
                       ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this did the job.